# Webapp2.Route regex issue

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine

I'm experiencing an issue where my get request in the browser returns 404 Resource cannot be found error, which seems to indicate that my webapp2.Route regex in the main.py is not matching the url.

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
[
webapp2.Route(r'/test_module/\?.*', handler=test_module.TestHandler, name='test_module'),
],
config=webapp2_config, debug=DEBUG)
```

The URL that I'm entering in the browser is

```
http://localhost:8080/test_module/?c=1
```

The reason I believe it's a regex issue is that if I change regex and URL to the following , the TestHandler runs with no problem.

```
webapp2.Route(r'/test_module', handler=...

http://localhost:8080/test_module
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried this

```
webapp2.Route(r'/test_module/', handler=test_module.TestHandler, name='test_module'),
```

i think you dont have to specify the ? in the router you can get these parameters by

```
self.request.get('c')
```